# Join NLA actions from multiple objects

Tags: animation, nla-editor, loop

I have 4 animations (one of each leg and arm of my lego man).  I want to be able to loop these animations multiple times throughout the scene to make the man walk.

Currently in the NLA Editor it has a separate track and action for each object (so 4 actions).   This is a bit of pain as every time i want to add another walk loop i have to duplicate all 4 actions.

I'd like to be able to merge, or link all 4 actions together into one "walk" action, so that I can just duplicate that 1 action to have the man do another walk cycle.

Is it possible?  And if so how?  See example of my NLA editor below:

[image]

Comment: So you have one armature but 4 different actions, one for each bone? How did you end up with this situation? If that's the case, what you could do is copy the keyframes of an action (for example left leg) and pasting it in the action of another object (for example right leg). But before pasting, you need to create a keyframe (whatever keyframe) for the second object (right leg), otherwise you won't be able to paste.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is an option for that.
Action is per object. So to have them in a single action you will need to parent them to Armature (each object to a single bone) and animate.

Select Object > Select Armature > Switch to Pose mode Ctrl+Tab > Parent to Bone Ctrl+P

---

In a current situation the only one thing that can help you a bit is increase **Repeat** option in NLA *Properties* > *Strip* tab > *Action Clip* panel for selected strip.

[image]

Note - In a case you will have **more tracks for one object** you can search for **Bake Action** to merge them by step 10 here.

[image]